# How to get total visited days and consecutives of an user?

Tags: support, discussion, feature-request, api, users

I checked [docs](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) , there are no endpoints to get total visited days and consecutive days. Is there any way to get them?

Comment: The closest is the ["Legacy Profiles"](https://stackapps.com/q/9074/58236) StackAPP which shows last visited, the Calendar is only available to: the user, moderators, and staff.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot get the days visited, nor consecutive, information for a user because [that is ***private* information**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317916/331508)<sup>(Poster is SE representative)</sup>.

Stack Exchange is *supposed* to be about the content, not the people.  And knowing people's (more detailed) visit history is a social metric, not an on-topic bit of information.
In a similar question, [one power-user put it succinctly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/132476/148310):

> It's nobody's business how addicted a user is. To see how active s/he is, check their "activity" tab. Rep tells you long-term activity, the activity tab/rep graph shows short-term activity. I think that's enough for anyone.
>
> We are NOT Facebook. Please don't make us Facebook.

---

That said, there might be some value in *statistics* comparing various metrics against days visited.  To that end, there is [a request to add this information to the Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276793/add-the-days-visited-metric-to-sede) which you should probably support, given your question here.

---

If you just want days visited and consecutive **for yourself**, or the logged-in user, you have to resort to screen scraping, for now.

For example, this code will scrape your info, if you are logged into a Stack Exchange page:

```js
var sqlch = $.get (
    "/users/" + StackExchange.options.user.userId + "/?tab=profile",
    function (pageTxt) {
        console.log ( $('#days-visited', pageTxt).text ().trim () );
} );
```

<sup>(Run the code from the browser console.)</sup>

You can also get a complete list of all the days you visited with an XHR call like this:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/users/daily-site-access/{YOUR_USER_ID}
```

Comment: Sorry for the question, but where can I find the given `YOUR_LOGGED-IN_SESSION_ID`?

Comment: The `_=xxx` param is actually a cache-busting param, so it isn’t really necessary. The session ID is sent as a cookie (`acct`).