# LegacyProfiles - Bringing back the old profile stats

Tags: script

### Preview

[image]

<sup>Note: The date is locale-based. Screenshot is in UTC</sup>

### What is LegacyProfiles? ([install](https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/raw/main/scripts/LegacyProfiles/legacyprofiles.latest.min.user.js), <sub>[unminified](https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/raw/main/scripts/LegacyProfiles/legacyprofiles.latest.user.js)</sub>)

LegacyProfiles brings back user info removed from profiles in a [recent profile update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/some-changes-to-the-profile-while-we-make-it-responsive). It is powered by [StackExchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/) and inspired by [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/410618/how-could-we-know-last-seen-and-people-views-in-profile/410627#410627).

Specifically, it allows you to see the user creation date, profile view count and when the user was last seen.

#### Browser Support

| IE | Chrome | Firefox | Safari | Edge | Opera |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ✔️ 6+ | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ 5.1+ | ✔️ 12.1+ | ✔️ 11.5+ |

#### Additional Information

| #### License | #### Suggestions/Issues |
| --- | --- |
| [MIT License](https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/blob/main/LICENSE) | Suggestions and issues should be raised as an answer in this post |

#### Changelog

- ###### v2.2

  - Replace native Last Seen field with data from API ([feature request](https://stackapps.com/a/9215/76056))
- ###### v2.1

  - Added support for Stack Exchange sites in a different language ([bug report](https://stackapps.com/a/9132/76056))
- ###### v2.0

  - Updated to work with [new profile changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369276/we-ve-shipped-some-changes-to-the-user-profile-navigation/)
- ###### v1.8

  - Updated human readable format engine (implemented in v1.3) to use singular when appropriate
- ###### v1.7

  - Fixed over-aggressive regex implemented in v1.5
- ###### v1.6

  - Fixed Greasemonkey bug (as reported [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/9074/legacyprofiles-bringing-back-the-old-profile-stats#comment18296_9074) and [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/9074/legacyprofiles-bringing-back-the-old-profile-stats#comment18298_9074))
- ###### v1.5

  - Better API quota conservation, only fetches user details when the current tab is the user's profile
- ###### v1.4

  - Revised selector
- ###### v1.3

  - Now displays how long ago the user was last seen in human readable format (e.g., "5 hours ago")
- ###### v1.2

  - Added API key, up request limit from 300 to 10000
- ###### v1.1

  - Icon color fixup

---

Languages/libraries used: [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)

Comment: Also couldn't get it to work in Greasemonkey. Works in Tampermonkey. FF 90.0.2, Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: @HolyBlackCat and DocBrown: Thanks for the report, the Greasemonkey issue has been patched in [v1.6](https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/tree/main/scripts/LegacyProfiles/v1.6)

Comment: BTW: All of the major userscript manager will automatically check for updates, if the URL from which the userscript is installed returns a script with a higher `version`. The "normal" expectation is that you just create a single file within your GitHub repository which is the userscript. New versions are just additional commits on that repository which update that single file, with all prior versions available in the commit history. In other words, having separate files/directories for "v1.4", "v1.5", "v1.6", etc. is detrimental, preventing the userscript manager from doing automatic updates.

Comment: Is it intentional that the "Member since" is put into the profile? It seems to have been put back by Stack using "Member for" with the exact time in a tooltip.

Comment: Tampermonkey issues some warnings about undefined globals and about unexpected assignments and sequences in a return statement. Adding  `/* globals jQuery, $ */` and `/* eslint-disable no-return-assign, no-sequences */` helps to suppress these warning.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm wondering if it's possible to swap the positions of month and day in the Member for/Last seen dates? [unfounded complaint from a UK user here :p]

Comment: @TheSimpliFire The format of the date is based on your browser's locale.

Comment: @Spectric: Is there a reason that the extended in formation is displayed on a user's Profile page, but not on the Activity page?

Comment: @MartinR the profile information list was originally only available on the Profile page. Only after the update was it also visible on the Activity page. I just haven't bothered to change it.

Comment: This might interest you https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372956/196432 (you probably have seen it already).

Comment: @MartinR thanks for the notice! I'll make sure that my userscripts will continue functioning after the change. :) Thanks again.

Comment: P.S. Git tags allows one to version specific commits via `git tag v4.2` and then `git push --tags`. This way, one does not need to maintain multiple folders with different versions since the tags already do that (and with other benefits).

Comment: @Sambhav.K You can install the userscript via the instructions here: https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/blob/main/how-to-install.md

Comment: @Spectric hmmm. Any free resources as it is not accessible on Safari, or Mac?

Comment: TamperMonkey is not free so it would be good if u can suggest a free one.

Comment: @Sambhav.K Did a quick search, this open source Safari userscript manager looks like it has some promise: https://github.com/quoid/userscripts

Comment: Ok. I did install it and from the extension, I created a new js script and then added that code. But, still I don't get that

Comment: Common open source alternatives to Tampermonkey are Violentmonkey and the original Greasemonkey. Of note is that TM is not "not free", it's just not open source.

Comment: Oh. I am sorry it works fine now. I had forgotten to save the script. Thanks

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine No, Tampermonkey for Safari 12+ is _literally not free_; it's [$1.99 on the macOS App Store](https://apps.apple.com/app/apple-store/id1482490089). It surprised me too; it's free on all other platforms. I'd assume that fee is used largely to cover Apple's dev fee to list it on the store.

Comment: @zcoop98 ha! Interesting, wow

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Here is what I see (but maybe I am not looking at the right place):

[image: Baluc]

After updating the script, creating a key, and a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (local storage) to enter said key:

<sup>Note: This step is no longer necessary since version 1.2+ includes an API key</sup>
[image: BalusC2]

Well done!

Comment: @Spectric As mentioned in https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/some-changes-to-the-profile-while-we-make-it-responsive?noredirect=1#comment1232103_368285... this is no longer working.

Comment: @VonC yeah, the most recent update broke a hell of a lot of scripts :( It was sort of anticipated, but still...

Comment: @VonC Fixed in v2.0

Answer (score 7):

I like the idea, but I would prefer for it to be on the second column on my profile, like this:

[image: one]

Which IMHO looks much nicer than the current version:

[image: two]

Looking at the source of your script, this can be achieved changing this specific selector from this:

```js
$('#user-card ul:not(.s-prose ul)').first().append(HTML);
```

To this:

```js
$('#user-card ul:not(.s-prose ul):eq(-1)').append(HTML);
```

The `-1` here instead of `1` is because on profiles different than your own there is no second column, so `-1` just selects the last column regardless.

Answer (score 6):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The [last seen field has been restored](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371145/196432) recently with a reduced granularity. As a consequence, *two* “Last seen” fields are presented if LegacyProfiles is active:

[image]

My suggestion is to *replace* the standard field instead, if that is possible.

Comment: I actually considered implementing this when the profiles were just updated, but I wasn't sure whether the users would like it. Looks like a good idea; I'll implement it in 2.2

Comment: @Spectric: There is a typo in the script: “profile viewss”

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me (I use Windows 10). I downloaded "Unminified", Version 1.3, then I opened the windows file explorer and double clicked on the file (6 KB). Then I get asked if I want to open the file, I say "yes" and then it says "microsoft jscript error 800A03EA". Is the tool supposed to be used differently? Are any instructions available?

Comment: Install a userscript manager in your browser (Greasemonkey for Firefox, Tampermonkey for other browsers), then click one of the install links. You will automatically be prompted to install the userscript.

Answer (score 4):

[status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

It would be great if this worked in Stack Overflow for Teams, for example in Charcoal and SOBiotics.

Comment: Try this [beta](https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/blob/main/beta/LegacyProfiles/sa9542-76056.js) which should work for Teams. If it works well I'll make it v2.3. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @Spectric, It doesn't work on another user's profile. [My profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8u2P.png) says both that I haven't visited for four months and that I have visited for 14 consecutive days; that's impossible. PS: I'm sure I installed it correctly, partly because of the bug, but would it be better if the version was incremented to 2.21; so the upgrade is more obvious. --- Thanks for trying.

Comment: Thanks! I've taken a look into it. It's showing you the last seen for the main site (stackoverflow.com: I'll try to fix that, although I don't think this data is accessible team-specifically), Also, LegacyProfiles doesn't change the 'visited for' part.

Comment: @Spectric,  It may be defaulting to [using the Stack Overflow main](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3648282/rob) ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scwUe.png)), but it's completely [broken on other sites](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1nQJ.png). [My main Meta profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/282094/rob) ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKYee.png)) doesn't show it working for me or [on your profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahTjA.png).

Comment: @Spectric,    Regarding this [comment](https://stackapps.com/questions/9074/legacyprofiles-bringing-back-the-old-profile-stats/9542?noredirect=1#comment18915_9542), https://stackoverflow.help/en/articles/4385859-stack-overflow-for-teams-api and the unnecessary workaround https://stackoverflow.com/a/68311795/3648282

Comment: @Spectric, Teams has changed its URL and the format of its profile page again: https://stackoverflowteams.com/c/sobotics/users/46/?tab=profile https://stackoverflowteams.com/c/charcoal/users/94/?tab=profile

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The script no longer works on [Russian SO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com).

For example, try looking at [this profile](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/195342/harry).

Comment: Thanks for the report. The bug has been patched in [v2.1](https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/tree/main/scripts/LegacyProfiles/v2.1)

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

I am currently using your Legacy profiles but cannot utilise the search users' functionality when doing so. This error occurs only on Safari.

Comment: Which userscript manager are you using in Safari? I had problems with a free userscript manager and then purchased Tampermonkey, which works fine so far. (That is my personal experience, I am not affiliated with any of these software products.)

Comment: Try and see if [this](https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/blob/main/beta/LegacyProfiles/sa9074-76056.js) works. Otherwise, it appears to be a problem with the userscript manager.

Comment: Ok @Spectric will try it out in the evening and let u know

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

I can't delete any of my profiles with my script anymore.

- I tried disabling all other scripts: this doesn't work.
- I tried disabling the LegacyProfiles script: this work.

When I have LegacyProfiles enabled, the button "Delete profile" is disabled even if checkbox is enabled:

> [image: screenshot]