# Bring back the layout!

Tags: script, design

> **Important notice**:
>
> [This update to site layout](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369276/786798) broke a lot of the layout adjusting scripts partially or completely. It affected my script as well - as of now, only pure-CSS adjustments work properly (like making use of the full page width). Due to the fact that the team is going to mess with the profile page layout further in the upcoming 6 to 8 weeks, I decided to not fix the broken parts until the layout is stable enough - please bear this in mind if you want to use the script or report an issue. In any case, the script degrades gracefully - you will simply see the new layout instead of some of the adjustments.

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

Profile page gap removal (before and after):

[image: profile page with the gap (before)]
[image: profile page without the gap (after)]

Profile page width restriction removal:

[image: profile page full width]

Activity tab making better use of screen space:

[image: activity tab full width]

Top bar menu stretching the full width of the viewport (before and after):

[image: top menu full width]
[image: top menu without the userscript]

### About

The recent [change to the profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368285/786798) layout in the name of "responsiveness" fails to properly use the screen real estate. Instead of waiting 6 to 8 weeks or the heat death of the universe*, you can use this simple userscript to make things right today.

The userscript is a living project, so more features will be added as we go. Please note that this script does not bring back removed stats, do check out [LegacyProfiles - Bringing back the old profile stats](https://stackapps.com/q/9074/78873) if you want them back too.

#### License

The script is licensed under the [GPL-3.0-or-later](https://spdx.org/licenses/GPL-3.0-or-later) license.

#### Download

[Install](https://github.com/userscripters/bring-back-layout/raw/master/dist/index.user.js) | [Minified](https://github.com/userscripters/bring-back-layout/raw/master/dist/index.min.user.js)

The script *doesn't need* a userscript manager to work (but includes necessary headers).

#### Platform

Version number means "last tested on":

| Chrome | Opera | Firefox | Edge | IE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ✔ 92.0.4515.107 | ✔ 77.0.4054.203 | ✔ 89.0 | ✔ 92.0.902.55 | no |

Userscript managers:

| Greasemonkey | Tampermonkey | Violentmonkey |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ✔ 4.11 | ✔ 31 | ✔ 2.13.0** |

Works well with:

| Userscript | Features | Author | Tested Version |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [Make better use of the space in profiles](https://stackapps.com/q/9080/78873) | Restores right sidebar on user profile and adds several UTC-based timestamps | [Little Nuts](https://stackapps.com/users/66653/little-nuts) | 1.1 |
| [Legacy Profiles](https://stackapps.com/q/9074/78873) | Allows you to see the user creation date, profile view count and when the user was last seen | [Spectric](https://stackapps.com/users/76056/spectric) | 1.4 |

### Change log

| Version | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 0.11.0 | significantly improved fullwidth styling |
| 1.0.0 | improved compatibility layer to better align with other userscripts |

<sub>Changelog prior to the last minor version can be found [in the revision history](https://stackapps.com/posts/9078/revisions)</sub>

### Contact

Author: [Oleg Valter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11407695/oleg-valter)

Organization: [UserScripters](https://github.com/userscripters)

Please, submit bug reports [on the source repository](https://github.com/userscripters/bring-back-layout).

Before adding a new one, please check if it hasn't been raised before.

You can also [drop by to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214345/userscript-newbies-and-friends), we are a friendly bunch.

### Code

[Source code](https://github.com/userscripters/bring-back-layout/blob/master/src/index.ts) written in TypeScript.

Contributions are welcome, you can always [submit a PR here](https://github.com/userscripters/bring-back-layout/pulls).

---

* credit goes to [Scratte](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/214345?m=52761915#52761915)
** thanks to [Kevin M. Mansour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14945696/) for testing this out

Comment: Change the Platform table, I have tested on Firefox 90.0.2. And Violent Monkey 2.13.0.

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour oh, I think I need to change the wording rather than the table itself :) What I mean is that support goes *as far as* meaning it should work on those specific options and higher. Unless you mean the script does not work for you, of course. In any case, thank you for confirming about Violentmonkey! It's been too many managers/browsers to test for me, so I played it safe by specifying that the support for it is unknown