# Make better use of the space in profiles, like profiles used to be

Tags: script, users

### About

The change to user profiles discussed in [Some changes to the profile while we make it responsive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/some-changes-to-the-profile-while-we-make-it-responsive) has introduced some empty space. It can be seen directly in [Profile page is very empty, revert to old version?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/410612/profile-page-is-very-empty-revert-to-old-version). Further development on the change to reponsiveness can be seen in

- [We’ve shipped some changes to the user profile navigation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369276/we-ve-shipped-some-changes-to-the-user-profile-navigation)
- [Now live: A fully responsive profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370964/now-live-a-fully-responsive-profile)

This script claims the space back.

It will also scrape the user profile's activity pages and insert:

- Marked with a   "⇑". The most recent/last activity skipping awards.
- Marked with a   "⇓". The very first activity including an award.
- Marked with a "⌚". The current time in UTC for easy comparison.

In addition, it

- Puts the trophies/badges under the "Posts", see [What is the new badge UI on the Profile page?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408611/what-is-the-new-badge-ui-on-the-profile-page).
- Removes the "Edit profile" quick link at the top right on own profiles, because it's on the "Settings" tab.
- Reduces the row on tags to the old 1 : 2 : 3 look.
- Adds a link to the network profile on the Community box.
- Moves meta posts to the left side column.
- Puts the meta/main link on the top bar.

Note that, especially on large profiles, it may seem a little slow due to at least trying to avoid rate limits.

From version 2.4 it also adds "profile views" and "Last seen", which is fetched from the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/) using [/users/{ids}](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-by-ids).

### Screenshot

Courtesy of [Vickel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2275490):

##### Before

[image: Before]

##### After

[image: After]

##### Link to network profile:

If there's no "View all" link in the "Communities" header, like in this one:

[image: Upper corner shows a link with the text View all]

the script will insert one:

[image: Upper corner shows a link using a Stack Inc logo]

##### Options

There are two variables at the top of the script that controls:

- Fetching "profile views" and "Last seen". Highlighed in red.
  Turn if off by setting this variable to false: `const getCreepyData = false;`
- Getting the first and last activity. Highlighed in blue.
  Turn if off by setting this variable to false: `const getActivity   = false;`

[image: ProfileviewsLastseenActivity]

#### Sites

Should work across the Stack Exchange network.

Those include:

- [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)
- [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)
- [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/)
- [スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)

However, the "profile views" and "Last seen" on these language sites are displayed in English. If there's a desire to have this displayed in the local language, please contact me for a *cooperation* on translation and re-work of the script.

#### Platform

Should work with any user script manager & any browser running JavaScript.
Tested with:

| User script manager | Version | Browser | Version |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TamperMonkey | 78.0.4093.112 | Opera | 4.13.6138 |
| Violent Monkey | 2.13.0 | Firefox | 90.0.2 |

Also tested and works in combination with

- <strike>[Bring back the layout!](https://stackapps.com/questions/9078/bring-back-the-layout)</strike> by [Oleg Valter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11407695). This script is temporarily slightly broken.
- [LegacyProfiles - Bringing back the old profile stats](https://stackapps.com/questions/9074/legacyprofiles-bringing-back-the-old-profile-stats) by [Spectric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14251221).
  To avoid getting the data twice, set the variable for *this script* to false:
  `const getCreepyData = false;`

#### Download

[GitHub](https://github.com/Scratle/fiddlings/tree/main/StackUserProfiles) | [Install](https://github.com/Scratle/fiddlings/raw/main/StackUserProfiles/StackUserProfiles.user.js) | [Tersed/Minified](https://github.com/Scratle/fiddlings/raw/main/StackUserProfiles/StackUserProfiles.ters.user.js)

### Contact

For bugs, please post here. Comments are fine too.

### Code

Vanilla JavaScript